Python Daylight Savings Accomodation
Iam working on a django project. Im fairly new to it. I have a requirement to sent out email reports in which I need to convert datetimes into yours local timezone. Im saving records in utc time and I have users time zone with me.
Iam using the python package pytz to convert utc time into user's local time. The convsersion is working fine. No issues there.
from pytz import timezone as pytz_timezone input_time.astimezone(pytz_timezone(time_zone) This is how i convert utc time into user's local time
Im confused with Daylight savings time. I want to know whether this conversion will also account for daylight savings?
Suppose the user is in New South Wales so he will have the time_zone as 'Australia/Sydney'. If the above mentioned code is applied during DST and not during DST , is it accounted in the conversion or do I need to add some other manipulation to the converted user local time to account for the DST. if so what should I do?
I hope my confusion and question makes sense.
Thanks in advance.

Specifically, this answer will highlight clearly that accounting for DST will work correctly and the timezone will switch between AEDT/AEST as per the rules.

@metatoaster it should be noted that the first linked duplicate might be misleading since it uses some outdated concepts, such as pytz and utcnow (both deprecated). Time zone handling is built into the standard library since Python 3.9, we have zoneinfo. The TL;DR answer is: yes, DST transitions are accounted for by the rules stored in the timezone database.

@FObersteiner OP asked specifically pytz so that's what I went with, but yes it is good to add that modern solutions are available.  That said, pytz is still maintained and is still a valid solution especially if that's being sought after.
